# Track user "path" to my website

Tags: web, google-analytics, analytics, packet

If i have a website A that receive a visit from a user U is possible to know just the website B where he come from or is possible to know "links" that the user have clicked to arrive at finally at our website

Example:

1 I search smartphone on google and went into a  smartphone blog
so

google.com (C) -> blogphone.com (B)

2 the user U click a link into the blog ( our B website ) and arrive on my website

blogphone.com (B) -> mywebsite.com (A)

Now i can know he come from (B) but how can i know the user visit previously google.com (C), its that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible as it is outside of the realm of your web property. There is a number of reasons why, including security, privacy, etc.

However, if blogphone.com (B) is a known affiliate of yours, then you could request them to pass through the referrer information in the URL.

You could then collect the referrer information from the URL and pass it through as a custom dimension.

Comment: firstly thanks for your answer, but if it is impossible to know that information without the support of the affiliate can such of this information be "triggered" thanks google analystics?

Comment: What i mean is that i think if (B) have incorporated google analystic code into his webpage maybe (A) can have this kind of informations I'm wrong?

Comment: Even if Google Analytics was tracking the user through their entire journey of 100+ websites, each of those datasets are separate. If you have access to multiple websites, you are able to set up trackers across those sites, however that is a different approach/problem then I believe you are asking for. By default you are not able to see the statistics of other websites beyond your own.